# Removing Accessors from an Object

Tags: c#

Give the following class:

```
public Person
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public string Age {get; set; }
}
```

If I wanted to then Return a IList is there anyway to return the List will all the Functionality of an IList but with the setters removed? Possibly with an extension method to remove the setters. I would Imagine you would have to use reflection but is this the only way that this could be done? Would it be feasible from a speed/implementation point of view.

I was just wondering how this could be done, it is not an actual design. And I am aware of just returning an IEnumerable, or IEnumerable with a skip or yield that would solve for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason for the name and age to have a public setter? If not you could do { get; private set; } and just set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with the setters removed from the Person class?   create

```
IReadonlyPerson
{
  string Name { get; }
  string Age { get; }
}
```

have Person implement it (it already does), then return a IList.  if you are talking about the mutability of the IList look at @RPM1984's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return a [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)?

Comment: if you use a ReadOnlyCollection you can still modify the values using the indexer like [0].Name = "New Name"; The only thing immutable is the collection itself I cant add/remove elements but I can still modify the internal values.

Comment: Yes, i know. I was unsure as to what you wanted to prevent. @Alex Lo's answer is the way to go in that case.